# OAuth redirect URL is not honored

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, api, oauth

Repro:

Logout from all Stack Exchange accounts, open:

https://stackexchange.com/oauth?client_id=375&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fcareers.stackoverflow.com%2fgateway%2fstack

After login, I got the Stack Exchange home page instead of careers.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Where did you get that URL from, anyway? It doesn't look anything like what I get when I try to log in to careers.SO.

Comment: This seems similar to something I see with SEDE. When I go to login after automatically being logged out, the URL appears to say I should be sent back where I came from, but I always get sent back to the SEDE homepage.

Comment: @Adam i understand it's an API bug judging from your edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry about that. Turns out, return URLs were broken on stackexchange.com entirely during signup and login. A fix is out now, so any API app auth redirect issues should also be resolved with it.

Please let me know if you see any other problems. Thanks for the report, and my apologies for the delay in fixing the issue.

Comment: Yessssssssssssssssssss <3

Comment: Well, less than 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Just verified and it works now. Thanks

Comment: What about [port number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308205/authentication-api-port-number-in-redirect-uri-is-ignored)?