# Is the Stack Exchange API Broken?

Tags: bug, api

I asked [this question](https://stackapps.com/questions/6938/implicit-flow-isnt-redirecting) a while ago on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/tour), but I've gotten absolutely no response, so I'm asking it here.

Is the Stack Exchange authorization process broken?

As I mentioned in the linked question, I've tried to run the implicit authentication flow in Chrome, [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge), [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) and my application; all of them just redirect to http://stackexchange.com without even asking the user for permission. This happens on two different machines (these are both Windows 10 machines, one on the latest Insider build and one on the public build, if that helps anything), so I'm 99% sure this has got to be a problem on the API's end, but no one will say anything about it. Is this a known issue? If so, is there an ETA for a fix? Or at least a workaround? I'm currently sitting dead in the water for the majority of features in my application, since I can't authorize.

Comment: Are you sure you configured the application to have this near the end *Desktop OAuth Redirect Uri Is Enabled* because I just tried it and your url works when I use one of my client_id's

Comment: @rene Yes, it's definitely enabled. As I mentioned in the linked question, this was all working fine and dandy for several months. Then suddenly, BOOM-- it died.

Comment: And you don't get the access_token on the url? Like so: `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=XZ8th`

Comment: Yeah, there's something broken with `redirect_uri` in there. We've received other reports as well. I'm looking into it.

Comment: @rene No, it never even asks for permission. It just hops to http://stackexchange.com.

Comment: @AdamLear Great, thanks! Please do let me know if a fix is applied.

Comment: @Adam is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280241/oauth-redirect-url-is-not-honored) the core issue? (In such case, isn't it better to close this as a dupe?)

Comment: @RareNCool Should be fixed now. Give it a go and let me know if there's any other issues?

Comment: @AdamLear Works! Thanks so much!