# Authentication API - port number in redirect_uri is ignored

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, authentication, oauth

We're using the API explicit flow for identity brokering in our [Keycloak SSO server](http://www.keycloak.org/) to provide users with the option for logging in using their Stack Overflow account.

Recently, we've noticed that Stack Exchange API seemingly started to ignore the port number specified in the `redirect_uri` parameter. E.g., when Keycloak is running on 8080 port, user is redirected back to port 80 (or 443 respectively if HTTPS was used) after logging in to Stack Exchange.

In other words, Stack Exchange is ignoring port number and is using the one based on current protocol leading to an error if Keycloak is running on a port which is non-default for given protocol.

After investigating this we were unable to find anything wrong on Keycloak's side.
For that reason I'd like to ask if anything changed in the API regarding the ports in redirect URIs, or if it's an issue and an unexpected behavior. If so, is there any way to officially report it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, none of us has ever gotten nonstandard ports to work.  Related posts on Stack Apps start with: https://stackapps.com/questions/4596/can-the-redirect-uri-contain-port-number.

Comment: A bug report here *is* the way to report it.  But if your company has a business relationship with Stack Exchange you may have additional options.  You can also try the contact form, linked at the bottom of this page.

Comment: Well, the nonstandard ports were working for us from the beginning. But then something broke.

Comment: Vasam, good to know. But define "beginning".  When did you start using the API with non-standard ports?

Comment: Sorry, by the beginning I meant cca March 2015.

Comment: Thanks.  I know I tested the problem extensively in 2014, and others have reported it a few times since. Good that it's working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the last build, ports in return `redirect_uri`s should be preserved.

In some cases the port will be stripped, but that should only happen if the port matches the default for the protocol.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick fix! I can confirm the issue was resolved and ports are now working as expected.