# How do we get the API build date/number?

Tags: feature-request, support, api

The API keeps [breaking and often gets fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+api+status-completed), all without a single peep in [the *Change Log*](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/change-log).

Officially the API is unchanged since version 2.2 in February of 2014.
But we know from [the resolved bugs here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+api+status-completed), and on Stack Apps, that this isn't true.  And the [developers admit as much](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308260/148310) with statements like:

> As of the last build, (your problem has been fixed)...

So **how do we get the build/compile/deploy date and the *real* version number** (EG: 2.2.6, or similar)?

I can find nothing in the API, nor the API docs that provides anything like this.  As previously mentioned, the change log does not.

---

#### Requested interface:

Ideally, this would be provided as a new route, perhaps `/status`, that returns:

1. Build/Compile/Deploy date in Unix epoch time (same as other API datetimes).
2. Precise/exact version number that increments with every single change.
3. Last outage time, or last start time, or runtime since last (re)start.

Comment: I expect #2 can be obtained in a hacker-ish way by parsing [all.js](https://dev.sstatic.net/apiv2/js/all.js) and find the line `setTimeout(function () { complete({ version: '29285' }); });` where I have reason to believe 29285 is the [TeamCity buildnumber](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248148/158100). But I'll confirm this when there is new build being pushed. While you have the exact version, it is not given there were changes related to the API. Having a true endpoint with this version info would be nice to have indeed.

Comment: @rene, that version has now incremented to `29348`.  Now, if only there was a diff mechanism we could see...